# Selecting a row after multiple groupings in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, time-series, windowing

i have a table in a postgres DB which has the following structure:

```
id | date | groupme1 | groupme2 | value
---------------------------------------- 
1  |  
2  |  
3  |
```

Now i want to achieve the following:

1. Grouping the table after groupme1 and groupme2
2. Get the value for every group
3. But only the last entry for each group-compination (odered after date)

Example:

```
 id | date | groupme1 | groupme2 | value
 ---------------------------------------
    |      |     A    |     1    |   4
    |      |     A    |     2    |   7
    |      |     A    |     3    |   3
    |      |     B    |     1    |   9
```

My current approach looks like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table AS a
JOIN (SELECT max(id) AS id
      FROM table
      GROUP BY groupme1, groupme2) AS b
ON a.id = b.id
```

The Problems of this approach:

- it asumes that higher dates have a higher id
- it takes long

Is there a faster and better way of doing this? Can windowing function help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by groupme1, groupme2 order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or, a better way to do this in Postgres uses `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (groupme1, groupme2) t.*
from t
order by groupme1, groupme2, date desc;
```

Comment: Both solutions work. Is this the fastest way? Running the second one over a datespan from the database of 7000 rows takes 4.8 seconds.

Comment: The second version is probably the fastest, and an index on `t(groupme1, groupme2, date desc)` would make it faster.